# How to search multiple text box from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I search multiple text boxes from a database using ASP.Net?

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {if (RefNo.Text == "@search")
            {
              string str = "Select [ITEM No#], [Company Name], [Discipline Required], [Service Description], Institution, [Award Date] from PSP_Report where ([ITEM NO#] like '%' + @search + '%')";
                SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RefNo.Text;
                con.Open();
                xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = xp;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "ITEM No#");
                Search.DataSource = ds;
                Search.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
            else if (CompanyName.Text == "@searche")
            {
                string str = "Select [ITEM No#], [Company Name], [Discipline Required], [Service Description], Institution, [Award Date] from PSP_Report where ([Company Name] like '%' + @searche + '%')";
                SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RefNo.Text;
                con.Open();
                xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = xp;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Company Name");
                Search.DataSource = ds;
                Search.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?. Please add more detail. We can´t be guessing what you want to do

Comment: Looks like you are searching more than one textbox.  Are you asking for a cleaner way or is there something broken in the code?  There's not a lot of detail or clarification here to answer the question... At least not from my quick glancing.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. If RefNo.Text is equal to `@search` then you are adding a parameter named `@search` with value equal to `@search`. The else block contains also an error. You use `@searche` but you add a parameter still named `@search`

Comment: Also ExecuteNonQuery is used for INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE operations, not for SELECTs and thus it has no place in your code above.

Comment: What to be able to search 5 text boxs at the same time from a database i wasn't sure about code to use. i'm still a beginner in this

Comment: I would appreciate to be given a direction on how to code an if statement to search multiple text boxs from a database

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I assume you have multiple text boxes on your search GUI, and you want to dynamically build a select statement based on user input.

one way to do is something like below. After you are sure the select is what you want then have a method to execute your query with your constructed select.

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Select [ITEM No#], [Company Name], [Discipline Required], [Service Description], Institution, [Award Date] from PSP_Report where 1=1 ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RefNo.Text))
        {
            str += $" and ([ITEM NO#] like '%'{RefNo.Text}'%')";                
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CompanyName.Text))
        { 
            str += $" and ([Company Name] like '%'{CompanyName.Text}'%')";
        }
```

PS:

- Be aware about SQL injection.
- I wouldn't use # or space on column names.